# Binary Search Tree Instantiaition

Tags: java, class, casting, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I have Created Binary Search Tree by Using a Tree Interface and Recursion (I am aware that using a Node Class I can Implement the same ) providing methods for Adding and Checking if an element is in the Binary Search Tree or not.

The Problem I am facing is in instantiating & displaying the elements of the BST.

Here is my code

**Tree Interface:**

```
package bst;

public interface Tree<D extends Comparable>{

    public boolean isempty();
    public int cardinality();
    public boolean member(D elt);
    public NonEmptyBst<D> add(D elt);

}
```

**EmptyBst Class:**

```
 package bst;

 public class EmptyBst<D extends Comparable> implements Tree<D>{
    public EmptyBst(){
        D data=null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isempty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int cardinality() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean member(D elt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public NonEmptyBst<D>add(D elt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new NonEmptyBst<D>(elt);
    }

}
```

**NonEmptyBst Class**

```
 package bst;

 public class NonEmptyBst<D extends Comparable> implements Tree<D> {
    D data;
    D root;
    Tree<D> left;
    Tree <D>right;

    public NonEmptyBst(D elt){
        data=elt;
        root=elt;
        left=new EmptyBst<D>();
        right=new EmptyBst<D>();

    }
    NonEmptyBst(){
        D dataThis=this.data;
    }
    public NonEmptyBst(D elt,Tree<D>leftTree,Tree<D>rightTree){
        data=elt;
        left=leftTree;
        right=rightTree;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isempty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int cardinality() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1+left.cardinality()+right.cardinality();
    }



    public boolean member(D elt) {
        if (data == elt) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (elt.compareTo(data) < 0) {
                return left.member(elt);
            } else {
                return right.member(elt);
            }
        }
    }

    public NonEmptyBst<D> add(D elt) {
        if (data == elt) {
            return this;
        } else {
            if (elt.compareTo(data) < 0) {
                return new NonEmptyBst(data, left.add(elt), right);
            } else {
                return new NonEmptyBst(data, left, right.add(elt));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BinarySearchTree Class**

```
package bst;
import bst.Tree;
import bst.EmptyBst;
import bst.NonEmptyBst;

public class BinarySearchTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        NonEmptyBst abcd=new NonEmptyBst( "abc");
        NonEmptyBst ab=new NonEmptyBst(67);

        abcd.add("cry me a river");
        abcd.add("geeehfvmfvf");
        abcd.add("I'm Sexy and i know it");
        abcd.add("zzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zzzfdsf");
        abcd.add("zzfedfrsd");
        abcd.add("tgrgdzsd");
        abcd.add("gtrgrtgtrgtrzzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zdddzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zzzzsd");
        abcd.add("zzzzsd");

    }
}
```

**
How Can I access the data at all nodes and then Print Them out?The Particular Problem I am facing is In Getting an exception namely `ClassCastException` when I access the "leaf Nodes" and even if I Initalize `new NonEmptyBst<D>`in My `NonEmptyBst<D>(D elt)` `constructor` I end Up having a null pointer Exception

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source) 
    at bst.NonEmptyBst.add(NonEmptyBst.java:51) 
    at bst.NonEmptyBst.add(NonEmptyBst.java:54) 
    at bst.BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:11)
```

Comment: What are you expecting `D dataThis=this.data;` to do? `this.data` is null at that point

Comment: I wanted to create an empty Instance of a `NonEmptyBst<D>` in order to create a "pointer" through which I could iterate through my `NonEmptyBst` and assign the data that pointer has to the data at the node at which I am currently "pointing to"

Comment: Where is the exception, then? Please show the stacktrace

Comment: Also, you never set `left` or `right`... Your `add` method is returning something, but you do nothing with those results

Comment: Does `add` modify the current tree or return a new tree?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
 at bst.NonEmptyBst.add(NonEmptyBst.java:51)
 at bst.NonEmptyBst.add(NonEmptyBst.java:54)
 at bst.BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:11)
` Yes, I forgot to add that,

Comment: @AndrewRueckert add function adds to the left and right according to the `data` which has been added in using `add(D elt)` if it is greater it adds to the right subtree else the left subtree

Comment: Regarding printing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure I see the need for `EmptyBst` unless you are trying to follow the design-pattern for a Null Object.

Specifically, an "empty" tree can easily be checked if `data == null && left == null && right == null`. Also, no need for `data` here, since it is a local variable and never referenced.

```
public EmptyBst(){
    D data=null; 
}
```

And is there a difference between `D data` and `D root`?

I think you need to adjust your `add` method to capture the result of the recursion.

```
public NonEmptyBst<D> add(D elt) {
    if (data == elt) {
        return this;
    } else {
        if (elt.compareTo(data) < 0) {
            this.left = this.left.add(elt);
        } else {
            this.right = this.right.add(elt);
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: I just used `D root` to print out the root element separately and for my own clarification as to where i can use the variable exclusively  and also was thinking of assigning  the element `elt` in my `NonEmptyBst<D>(D elt)` constructor as the root of the any BST that i create. and can use it to define a method to find `parent node ` of  any given node

Comment: You are assigning `root` and `data` to the same element, though. If you want a `NonEmptyBst<D> parent` variable, then that's something different

Comment: yes still thinking of a way about it. I  Have to try out your suggestion above first and get my Bst to atleast display all its "nodes" which will help me develop some confidence in this approach , specifically with using interfaces then  I might come around to solving the `parent` problem

Comment: The other answer here gets the nodes in a list, but you can replace the `l.add` with a print statement of the nodes data to see your tree

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to print all elements though.

Comment: I believe I answered how to fix the error. Your posts should stay at one question. If would like to ask another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Your suggestions were more than helpful! The printing part is trivial in comparison to the major problem the code was having

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it recursively. As I don't have your node implementation I'll write a general example:

```
// Return a list with all the nodes
public List<Node> preOrder() {
    List<Node> l = new ArrayList<Node>();
    l.add(this.value); // Add the data of the root
    if(this.left != null) // Add elements to the left
        l.addAll(this.left.preOrder());
    if(this.right != null) // Add elements to the right
        l.addAll(this.right.preOrder());
    return l;
}
```

Then you would simply call it:

```
List<Node> nodes = myTree.preOrder();
```

And then loop through the list to do whatever you want.

Comment: Should probably use `instanceof EmptyBst` instead of a null check

Comment: No, he should use the method he created `isEmpty` instead. Instanceof breaks polymorphism in this case.

Comment: Fair point. I was mostly pointing out that they shouldn't be null